# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have just 2 objects and simple query to retrieve the data.

The result of query which is stored in array `ccList` according to debug output is:

```
(
    CustomThree__c:
    {
    Name=cusmei3 2, 
    customOne__c=a005000000IwnOPAAZ, 
    Id=a025000000FsFGQAA3
    }, 
    CustomThree__c:
    {
    Name=cusmei3 1, 
    customOne__c=a005000000IwnOUAAZ, 
    Id=a025000000FsFGLAA3
    }
)
```

As you can see `system.debug(ccList[0])` returns:

```
CustomThree__c:{
    Name=cusmei3 2, 
    customOne__c=a005000000IwnOPAAZ, 
    Id=a025000000FsFGQAA3
}
```

But when I try to get `Id` (or other field) from the array, the error occurs.
Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

**code**

```
Object[] ccList;
ccList = [SELECT id, name, CustomOne__r.name  FROM CustomThree__c];
system.debug(ccList);
system.debug('******************************************');
system.debug(ccList[0]);
system.debug(ccList[0].Id); //this one cause the error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to change the type of ccList from "Object" to "CustomThree__c". This will also give you compile-time checking when you'll try to write `ccList[0].SomeNonExistentFieldName__c`.

If you can't do it and really need the object that stores result to be generic - I believe this should be SObject?